# Reshaping data from long to wide

Tags: sas

Below is an example that I found to reshape data from long to wide.But I am not able ti understand the code, especially the way they are replacing blanks and why. Can someone help me understand the code?

Example 1:  Reshaping one variable

We will begin with a small data set with only one variable to be reshaped.  We will use the variables year and faminc (for family income) to create three new variables:  faminc96, faminc97 and faminc98.  First, let's look at the data set and use proc print to display it.

```
DATA long ; 
  INPUT famid year faminc ; 
CARDS ; 
1 96 40000 
1 97 40500 
1 98 41000 
2 96 45000 
2 97 45400 
2 98 45800 
3 96 75000 
3 97 76000 
3 98 77000 
; 
RUN ;
PROC PRINT DATA=long ;
RUN ;
Obs    famid    year    faminc

 1       1       96      40000
 2       1       97      40500
 3       1       98      41000
 4       2       96      45000
 5       2       97      45400
 6       2       98      45800
 7       3       96      75000
 8       3       97      76000
 9       3       98      77000
```

Now let's look at the program.  The first step in the reshaping process is sorting the data (using proc sort) on an identification variable (famid) and saving the sorted data set (longsort).  Next we write a data step to do the actual reshaping.  We will explain each of the statements in the data step in order.

```
PROC SORT DATA=long OUT=longsort ;
 BY famid ;
RUN ;

DATA wide1 ;
  SET longsort ;
  BY famid ;

  KEEP famid faminc96 -faminc98 ;
  RETAIN faminc96 - faminc98 ;

  ARRAY afaminc(96:98) faminc96 - faminc98 ;

  IF first.famid THEN
  DO;
    DO i = 96 to 98 ;
      afaminc( i ) = . ;
    END;
  END;

  afaminc( year ) = faminc ;

  IF last.famid THEN OUTPUT ;

RUN;
```

Comment: Also you can explore as an alternative proc transpose; example code proc transpose data=dataset out=reqd_ds; by famid; id year; var faminc; run;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good example to compare and contrast with DO UNTIL(LAST.   It does away with the RETAIN and INIT to missing on FIRST.FAMID and the LAST. test for when to OUTPUT.  Those operations are sill done just using the built in features of the data step loop.

```
DATA long; 
   INPUT famid year faminc; 
   CARDS; 
1 96 40000 
1 97 40500 
1 98 41000 
2 96 45000 
2 97 45400 
2 98 45800 
3 96 75000 
3 97 76000 
3 98 77000 
;;;; 
   RUN;
proc print;
   run;
data wide;
   do until(last.famid);
      set long;
      by famid;
      ARRAY afaminc[96:98] faminc96-faminc98;
      afaminc[year]=faminc;
      end;
   drop year faminc;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: This approach is called as DO loop of Whitlock (DOW) or Dorfman/Whitlock Loop. To understand what is happening have a look at e.g. http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/156-2012.pdf

Comment: @Jetzler Check this out -30 years. http://www.sascommunity.org/sugi/SUGI83/Sugi-83-171%20Henderson.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the new way. I am just wondering if we should use the retain and reset statements here?

Comment: @user6037890 You don't need retain because the values FAMINCnn are not initialized to missing until the start of a new by group FAMID.

Answer (score 0):

The main element here is the SAS retain statement.
The datastep is executed for every observation in the dataset. For every iteration all variables are set to missing and then the data is loaded from the dataset.
If a variable is RETAINed it will not be reset, but will keep the information from the last iteration.

```
BY famid ;
```

Your dataset is ordered and the datastep is using a by statement. This will initialize the `first.famid` and `last.famid`. These are just binaries that turn to 1 for the first/last observation of a single id-group.

```
RETAIN faminc96 - faminc98 ;
```

As already explained `faminc96 - faminc98` will keep their value from one datastep iteration to the next.

```
ARRAY afaminc(96:98) faminc96 - faminc98 ;
```

Just an array, so you can call the variables by number instead of name.

```
  IF first.famid THEN
  DO;
    DO i = 96 to 98 ;
      afaminc( i ) = . ;
    END;
  END;
```

For every first observation in an id-group the retained variables are reset. Otherwise you would keep values from one od-group to the next. Same could be done by `IF first.famid then call missing(of afaminc(*));`

```
afaminc( year ) = faminc ;
```

Writing the information to your transposed variables, according to the year.

```
 IF last.famid THEN OUTPUT ;
```

After you have written all the values to your new variables, you only OUTPUT one observation (the last) in every id-group to the new dataset. As the variables were retained, they are all filled at this point.

This datastep is fast and purpose build. But generally you could just use `proc transpose`

Comment: This helps me understand the concept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend proc transpose. It'll make your life easier.

http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/060-2009.pdf